# why nvcc remove my if branch during compiling?

Tags: cuda

I found a strange behaviour when compiling cuda code to ptx. If global function using return value from `tex2DLod<uchar4>` calls a device function with if-statement whose both branches contain a device function using uchar4 as argument, the resulting ptx file only has the code from else branch.

An example is here. I compiled the following code with both cuda 10.1 update 1 and update2. Result is always the same. When I remove the if statement and only put the else part there. The resulting ptx never changes which means the first branch has lost.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cuda.h>
__device__ float3 rgba2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.x/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.z/255.0f);
}
__device__ float3 bgra2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.z/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.x/255.0f);
}
__device__ float3 pixel2rgb(uchar4 p, bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        return bgra2rgb(p);
    }
    else
    {
        return rgba2rgb(p);
    }
}

extern "C" __global__ void func2(
    CUtexObject rgb_mip_texture,
    size_t width, size_t height,
    bool flag
)
{
    size_t x_p = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t y_p = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;


    if (x_p >= width || y_p >= height)
        return;
    uchar4 pixel = tex2DLod<uchar4>(rgb_mip_texture, x_p, y_p, (float)0);
    //uchar4 pixel = make_uchar4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    float3 rgb = pixel2rgb(pixel, flag);
    printf("rgb=(%f,%f,%f)", rgb.x, rgb.y, rgb.z);
}
```

the nvcc command ccbin is `clang 8.0`.

```
/usr/bin/nvcc -ptx \
    -v --ptxas-options=-v \
    --compiler-options "-v" \
    -ccbin "${ccbin}" \
    "${input_file}" \
    -o "${ptx_file}"
```

If the `pixel` is not from `tex2DLod` (for example from a `make_uchar4`) then both branches are preserved. Is this a known bug in nvcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be a bug in nvcc 10.1 (the only version I have tested). It appears that the compiler attempts at automatic inline expansion of the `rgba2rgb` and `bgra2rgb` functions are breaking somehow, so that the result of compiling this:

```
__device__ float3 pixel2rgb(uchar4 p, bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        return bgra2rgb(p);
    }
    else
    {
        return rgba2rgb(p);
    }
}
```

is effectively this:

```
__device__ float3 pixel2rgb(uchar4 p, bool flag)
{
    return rgba2rgb(p);
}
```

It isn't related to textures per se, because I can reproduce the problem with this code reading directly from global memory:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cstdio>

__device__ float3 rgba2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.x/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.z/255.0f);
}
__device__ float3 bgra2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.z/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.x/255.0f);
}
__device__ float3 pixel2rgb(uchar4 p, bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        return bgra2rgb(p);
    }
    else
    {
        return rgba2rgb(p);
    }
}

__global__ void func2(
    uchar4* pixels,
    size_t width, size_t height,
    bool flag
)
{
    size_t x_p = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t y_p = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((x_p < width) && (y_p < height)) {

    size_t idx = x_p * width + y_p;
    uchar4 pixel = pixels[idx];
    float3 rgb = pixel2rgb(pixel, flag);

    printf("flag=%d idx=%ld rgb=(%f,%f,%f)\n", flag, idx, rgb.x, rgb.y, rgb.z);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int width = 2, height = 2;
    uchar4* data;
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, width * height * sizeof(uchar4));

    data[0] = make_uchar4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    data[1] = make_uchar4(2, 3, 4, 5);
    data[2] = make_uchar4(3, 4, 5, 6);
    data[3] = make_uchar4(4, 5, 6, 7);

    dim3 bdim(2,2);
    func2<<<1, bdim>>>(data, width, height, true);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    func2<<<1, bdim>>>(data, width, height, false);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}

$ nvcc  -arch=sm_52 -o wangwang wangwang.cu 
$ ./wangwang 
flag=1 idx=0 rgb=(0.003922,0.007843,0.011765)
flag=1 idx=2 rgb=(0.011765,0.015686,0.019608)
flag=1 idx=1 rgb=(0.007843,0.011765,0.015686)
flag=1 idx=3 rgb=(0.015686,0.019608,0.023529)
flag=0 idx=0 rgb=(0.003922,0.007843,0.011765)
flag=0 idx=2 rgb=(0.011765,0.015686,0.019608)
flag=0 idx=1 rgb=(0.007843,0.011765,0.015686)
flag=0 idx=3 rgb=(0.015686,0.019608,0.023529)
```

I presume that the `make_uchar4` version you mention works because the compiler will do pre-computation of the results due to the constant inputs and eliminate the conversion function code all together.

Playing around, I was able to fix this by changing the code like this:

```
__device__ __inline__ float3 rgba2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.x/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.z/255.0f);
}
__device__ __inline__ float3 bgra2rgb(uchar4 p)
{
    return make_float3(p.z/255.0f, p.y/255.0f, p.x/255.0f);
}
```

When I do this, the compile injects some swizzling logic into the inline PTX expansion it generates:

```
    ld.global.v4.u8         {%rs2, %rs3, %rs4, %rs5}, [%rd10];
    and.b16         %rs8, %rs1, 255;   <---- %rs1 is the input bool
    setp.eq.s16     %p4, %rs8, 0;
    selp.b16        %rs9, %rs2, %rs4, %p4;
    and.b16         %rs10, %rs9, 255;
    selp.b16        %rs11, %rs4, %rs2, %p4;
    and.b16         %rs12, %rs11, 255;
```

and things work correctly (your mileage may vary):

```
$ nvcc  -arch=sm_52 -o wangwang wangwang.cu 
$ ./wangwang 
flag=1 idx=0 rgb=(0.011765,0.007843,0.003922)
flag=1 idx=2 rgb=(0.019608,0.015686,0.011765)
flag=1 idx=1 rgb=(0.015686,0.011765,0.007843)
flag=1 idx=3 rgb=(0.023529,0.019608,0.015686)
flag=0 idx=0 rgb=(0.003922,0.007843,0.011765)
flag=0 idx=2 rgb=(0.011765,0.015686,0.019608)
flag=0 idx=1 rgb=(0.007843,0.011765,0.015686)
flag=0 idx=3 rgb=(0.015686,0.019608,0.023529)
```

I would report this as a bug to NVIDIA.